# I accidentally sent a token to a token contract. Can I get it back? $MWAT

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, contract-debugging, etherscan

community!

Instead of transferring my ERC20 token $MWAT (RED PLATFORM) to my wallet, I accidentally sent it to the contract itself

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe6ffc7441c8a976ad3677b7a63b41f989698c20466e660bc0a71e5e3ba84dc64

On contract address there're also stuck tokens..
https://etherscan.io/address/0x6425c6be902d692ae2db752b3c268afadb099d3b

Would the contract creator be able to send it back to me?
Maybe some chances to send it back?
Or contract could expire in 5/10 years and send back to origin wallet?

Comment: sorry, No the owner cannot do this. The owner cannot mint tokens for you, cause the mintingFinished = True (is finished) in contract and  the owner cannot transfer token on behalf of the contract.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way for you to get them back, tokens sent to that particular contract that you're referring to, are stuck there forever. The contract that you link to has no way to withdraw tokens mistakenly sent to it.

Perhaps your best chance is to reach out to the MWAT team and explain your situation, perhaps they can try to resolve it in someway.